# What is the meaning of the '=>' symbol in the output of 'ldd' command in Linux linker?

Tags: linux, linker, dynamic-linking, ldd

when I run 'ldd some_executable_file', it shows dependencies required by this exe, like "libm.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007ff2eaf52000)".
while some dependencies in the list appearing in the form "some_absoulute_path/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007ff2eba92000)",it seems that the left side file does not points to the right side file

according to some tests, the left side file was choosed as dependency path while the right side file was not, so what does the symbol "=>" mean?

Comment: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ldd.1.html. Might be an *XY Problem*. Please provide the exact command, environment and output.

Comment: I wanted to use clang to compile my code, but it shows relocation error "symbol _dl_starting_up, version GLIBC_PRIVATE not defined in file ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 with link time reference". So I input "ldd clang" to see what's the loader it depends, here's what it showed(some items were omited from the list) :
$ ldd clang
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffe1d7d0000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /tools/gnu/gcc/gcc-8.2.0/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fe03688b000)
        /opt/compiler/gcc-8.2/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fe03774e000)

Comment: It turns out that the loader it relies on is what displays on the left side"/opt/compiler/gcc-8.2/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2" other than the right side " /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2". So I wanted to figure out what does the "=>" mean, which I did not find any discription in the manual page

Comment: And when I switch to another clang compiler that depends on "/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2", it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `ldd` output is misleading (at least for binaries which do not use the system `ld-linux`).

About 10 years ago, `ldd` used the *actual* program interpreter "baked into" the binary (the `some_absoulute_path/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` here).

However, this was deemed a security risk, because a root user might run `ldd some-foreign-binary` and that would cause the "baked in interpreter" to run as root, which isn't necessarily what the system administrator expected.

So now `ldd` uses the *system* `ld-linux` regardless of "baked in" interpreter, and that causes the "wrong" output here:

```
some_absoulute_path/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 ...
```

If you were to *actually* run the binary, it wouldn't use `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`; it would use the actual "baked in" interpreter `some_absoulute_path/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`.

To get *accurate* `ldd` result, you should run the `ldd` that matches `some_absoulute_path/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`. Here it's probably  `/opt/compiler/gcc-8.2/bin/ldd`.